# Firefox CloneInto does not copy function from add-on script to page script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey, userscripts

I created a Greasemonkey script that contains an object that I would like to make accessible from the internal scripts of the page.

To do so, there are several safe ways described on [this page](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/).
One of them is to use the [Components.utils.cloneInto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.cloneInto) function.

Here is a script example.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test CloneInto
// @namespace   Test CloneInto
// @description Test CloneInto
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var myObj = {}

myObj.test = function() {
  alert("works");
}

myObj.num = 152;

unsafeWindow.myObj = cloneInto(myObj, unsafeWindow, {cloneFunctions: true});

var scriptDOM = document.createElement("script");
scriptDOM.type = "text/javascript";
scriptDOM.innerHTML = "alert(window.myObj.num);\
                       alert(window.myObj.test);"
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptDOM);
```

"152" is displayed correctly, but then "undefined" appears instead of my function.
Yet I used `{cloneFunctions: true}` as suggested by the documentation.

I use Firefox 34, would anyone have an idea to fix this please?

**Edit:** It works just fine using Google Chrome and Tampermonkey.
**Edit 2:** Opened [issue 2070 on the Greasemonkey repository](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2070).

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug in Greasemonkey itself. Haven't confirmed that yet.

Comment: @BrockAdams Actually, I do not know if it comes from GreaseMonkey or Firefox. I opened an issue on Greasemonkey Github, will see.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never :)

You probably already discovered this. You might just have a syntax error because a semicolon was missing.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test CloneInto
// @namespace   Test CloneInto
// @description Test CloneInto
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==
var myObj = {};
myObj.test = function() {
  alert("works");
};
myObj.num = 152;
unsafeWindow.myObj = cloneInto(myObj, unsafeWindow, {cloneFunctions: true});
```

Works just fine in FireMonkey as a user-script.
When I open the Developer Tools (F12) and write

```
myObj
```

it displays

```
Object { test: (), num: 152 }
```

Keep on the good work!

Answer (score -1):

> To do so, there are several safe ways [described on this page.](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/)

This is describing a change to the Add-on SDK content scripts.

The change is not related to Greasemonkey or user scripts, Addon-sdk content scripts are a different thing than Greasemonkey user scripts.

For Greasemonkey I think this still works:

`unsafeWindow.myObj = myObj`